# How to create a server with sim800l module?

Tags: server, arduino, gsm

I have bought the sim800l module and managed to connect to the internet as a client, but now I want to know if it is possible to create a GSM server with this module, I have seen examples but with the arduino libraries, which are for a sim900 module, but I have not found some AT commands that achieve the same effect, I leave you part of the source code used until now.

```
  void iniciar(){
       comandoAT("AT","OK",3000); // Comprueba que el modulo SIM800L esta arrancado
       Serial.println("Conectando a la red...");
       delay(3000);
       while(!comandoAT("AT+CREG?","+CREG: 0,1",1000)); //Espera hasta estar conectado a la red movil
       Serial.println("Conectado a la red.");
       comandoAT("AT+CGATT=1", "OK", 1000); //Iniciamos la conexión GPRS
       comandoAT("AT+CSTT=\"internet.comcel.com.co\",\"comcel\",\"comcel\"", "OK", 3000); //Definimos el APN, usuario y clave a utilizar
       comandoAT("AT+CIICR", "OK", 3000); //Activamos el perfil de datos inalámbrico
       comandoAT("AT+CIFSR", "", 3000); //Obtenemos nuestra IP
  }

  void peticion(){
      char aux_str[50];
      char direccion[] = "GET /asciilogo.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: arduino.cc\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
      if(comandoAT("AT+CREG?","+CREG: 0,1",1000)){ //Comprueba la conexion a la red
          comandoAT("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"arduino.cc\",\"80\"","CONNECT OK",5000); //Inicia una conexión TCP
          // Envíamos datos a través del TCP
          sprintf(aux_str, "AT+CIPSEND=%d", strlen(direccion));
          if (comandoAT(aux_str,">",10000))
          {
            comandoAT(direccion, "OK", 10000);
          }
      }else{
          Serial.print("Reiniciando...");
          iniciar();
      }
  }
```

Sorry about the English.

Answer (score 1):

The sim800l module is a network interface, in this case to a GSM/GPRS network.

In theory, if you set up our Adrunio as a server then it can use any interface to send and receive messages from clients, provided your network provider supports HTTP requests to that interface.

However, many mobile network providers may not allow incoming HTTP requests, and even if they do their translation between the internal IP address assigned to your modem within their network and the external IP address that you would see if you access it from the internet may change over time which could easily be an issues for your solution.